# What is the cardinality of $A$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Consider a set $$A = \left \{(x_n)_{n \geq 1}\ |\ x_n \in \{0,1 \}\ \text {for all}\ n \geq 1\  \text {and}\ x_n = 0\ \text {for all but finitely many}\ n \in \Bbb N \right \}.$$

Then what is the cardinality of $A$?

Clearly it doesn't exceed $2^{\aleph_0}.$

Comment: Can it be countable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Each member of $A$ is the characteristic (or indicator) function of a finite subset of $\Bbb Z^+$.

Comment: So it remains to find how many finite subsets of $\Bbb Z^+$ are there? Am I right sir? I have realized it before but don't know anything about it's cardinality.

Comment: @Anacardium: You are indeed right. Do you know how many subsets of $\Bbb Z^+$ there are of cardinality $n$, where $n$ is some positive integer?

Comment: For any $n \geq 1$ I think there are countably many subsets of $\Bbb Z^+$ of cardinality $n.$ Now if I use countable unions of countable set is countable I think we are through.

Comment: @Anacardium: Right again. And the union of countably many countable sets is ... ?

Comment: Sir is it a silly question? Can I be downvoted for it? If so, I will delete my question.

Comment: @Anacardium: I certainly wouldn’t downvote it; I suspect that there are some people here who would, because it’s probably been answered here before in some version. Anyway, the answer to the question that you asked just under it is *yes*: it’s a countably infinite set.

Answer (score 1):

For each member of $A$, it is tempting to assign the following nonnegative integer:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_{n+1} 2^n$$
i.e. treating the the zeros and ones as binary digits of a whole number. The series is essentially a finite sum because almost all $x_n$ are zero.

This gives an explicit bijection (prove it) between $A$ and $\mathbb{Z}^{\ge 0}$, so by definition the cardinality of $A$ is only $\aleph_0$.